# Is there an easy way in C (AVR programming) to choose if a variable should be stored in RAM or ROM and handle it through all the code?

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I find myself in many situations that I should have stored an array or bunch of structures in ROM instead of RAM. Then I go through all the code and make changes like adding PROGMEM, pgm_read_word(), pgm_read_byte(). It is a hard task to do especially after writing like 4000 lines of code.

Is there a trick that could be done to do this easier?

Comment: A trick? Using a compiler which properly supports the architecture would be a start. You shouldn't _have_ to bother with `pgm_read_read` business, the reasonable way is a qualifier to mark program memory spaces.

Comment: memory placement is usually handled by the linker

Comment: @user3528438: The linker allocates variables _within_ an address space, it typically does not select which segment to place them into. The AVR in particular is a Harvard architecture with requires different types of instructions to be generated for ROM vs RAM, the former being somewhat restricted in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using GCC's [named address spaces](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html) feature.  This feature was enabled for AVRs in GCC 4.7, so you'll have to make sure you are using GCC 4.7 or later.  This will allow you to specify to the compiler what memory space your variables are in, and what memory space your pointers point to.  Then you can access the variables with regular C syntax instead of using functions like `pgm_read_byte`.

**Note:** As of GCC 4.9.2, the named address spaces are only supported in the GNU C compiler, *not* the C++ compiler, which the Arduino IDE uses.

Comment: It did work thank you  I did the following:

To define a new flash array:
`const __attribute__((__flash)) int  my_array[4]={1,2,3,4}`

I accessed it as a normal array, here I printed the last item in my_array
`Serial.println(String(my_array[3]))`

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Why should anybody struggle with `PROGMEM` and `pgm_read_byte()` if there is an easier and a more flexible way to get the job done?

Comment: GCC 4.7.0 was released in 2012 and it took longer for it to become universally available.  There was a lot of AVR development work done before then.

Comment: I am sorry for the misinformation that I gave, After creating many `__attribute__((__flash))`  arrays it appeared that these arrays are getting stored in RAM !!

Comment: What about just `__flash` without the attribute stuff, like it is shown in the GCC documentation I linked to?

Comment: `const __flash  char ST_MAIN_SCREEN_ROM[]                                = "This is main screen";`
The compiler shows the following error
error: '__flash' does not name a type

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?  Could you paste the output of `avr-gcc -v`?  Also, how are you invoking `avr-gcc`?  The `--std` option can disable `__flash` depending on what value you use for it, because `__flash` is a non-standard GCC extension, but the extension seems to be enabled by default if you do not pass `--std`.

Comment: I am using the arduino IDE 1.8.1 version which I believe it uses gcc-4.9.2.

Comment: Oh.  Your question indicates in multiple ways that you are using C but the Arduino IDE actually uses C++, and it seems that GCC's C++ compiler does not support the `__flash` qualifier unfortunately.  I just did a quick test with avr-gcc and avr-g++ 4.9.2 from Atmel's toolchain to confirm this.  Since the question you asked is about C, I suggest marking my answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually I used the C++ tag for the question and then unfortunately @François Andrieux deleted it. But nevermind thank you for your effort.